# How to add a custom class in v8?

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading, v8

Thank you for reading my question.

I am trying to embbed google V8 to my game engine. 
Now I need to add a Bytes(or Buffer, in node.js) class to my program. I have read the implentation of Buffer in node.js, but, that's too ugly in my mind.

The class what I want is like bytes class in python, which can decode to string and be encoded to from string, and have its own operator such as '+' and '*'.

It seems the only way is to modify the V8 itself?

I spent 2 days reading the code in V8, but getting more and more chaos. For example, the String class has 2 declarations: in v8.h and objects.h, and big diffirences exist in both. The terrible big macros are making me crazy, too.

My question is the same as this: [How to add a new class to Google V8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929716/how-to-add-a-new-class-to-google-v8) , but yiding thinks he/she does not need to modify V8.

Then I asked the same questions, too:

**Where can I find guides about modifying V8's code?**

**Or where can I find docs about V8's design architecture?**

Comment: Well it is impossible to have the operator overloading unless you are willing to do it yourself and doing significant modifications to the core code.

Comment: I think if I add a built-in type to v8, the operator syntax will have effect on the new type, won't it?

Comment: No, the language doesn't, and never will, have operator overloading so why would there be any code for that? It would not be exaggeration to say that it is easier to create your own engine from scratch for your new language than modify v8 to support it.

Comment: But js must process the plus operator itself, such as a string plus another string. I want to copy that code if I can find it.

Comment: Rules 1 to 27 of embedding V8: You Don't Want To Modify Internal V8 Code. Seriously. You don't want that. Let alone for peculiarities like  custom "overloading". (Just to set you straight, + is implemented on perhaps 2 dozens of different code paths, realising different optimisations and specialisations. Extending any of that to a new type will take even a V8 dev several months.)